# ROC curve fit characteristic

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, roc

I have a question:

> Is the ROC curve enough to assess goodness of fit? Or do you need other tests?

Comment: Your question is vague and would benefit from clarification. In what context are you using a ROC curve? What do you mean by goodness of fit in this situation? Edit your question and include a concrete example of your problem. Try reading the three papers I suggested below to better organize your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following papers will address your question:

1. Walsh SJ. Goodness-of-fit issues in ROC curve estimation. Med Decis Making. 1999 Apr-Jun;19(2):193-201. PMID: 10231082.
2. Zou, K.H., et al. Receiver-Operating Characteristic Analysis for Evaluating Diagnostic Tests and Predictive Models. Circulation.2007; 115: 654-657doi: 10.1161/​CIRCULATIONAHA.105.594929
3. Zou, K.H., et al. A global goodness-of-fit test for receiver operatingcharacteristic curve analysis via the bootstrap method. Journal of Biomedical Informatics. http://www.spl.harvard.edu/archive/spl-pre2007/pages/papers/zou/Zou2005GOF.pdf

Here is an example of how to do a goodness of fit analysis using SAS: http://www.sfu.ca/sasdoc/sashtml/stat/chap39/sect49.htm